# Java collection question for representing a social network from Testdome

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, collections

Given a data structure representing a social network, write a function that finds friends of a certain degree. Friends of the first degree are a member's immediate friends, friends of the second degree are friends of a member's friends excluding first degree friends, etc.

This problem url: https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/friends/331

How can I write getFriendsOfDegree(Member member, int degree) method?

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;

class Member {
    private String email;
    private Collection<Member> friends;

    public Member(String email) {
        this(email, new ArrayList<Member>());
    }

    public Member(String email, Collection<Member> friends) {
        this.email = email;
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Collection<Member> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void addFriends(Collection<Member> friends) {
        this.friends.addAll(friends);
    }

    public void addFriend(Member friend) {
        friends.add(friend);
    }
}

public class Friends {
    public static List<Member> getFriendsOfDegree(Member member, int degree) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Member me = new Member("me@test.com");
        Member myFriend = new Member("my.friend@test.com");
        Member myFriendsFriend = new Member("my.friends.friend@test.com");

        me.addFriend(myFriend);
        myFriend.addFriend(myFriendsFriend);

        for (Member friend : getFriendsOfDegree(me, 2))
            System.out.println(friend.getEmail());
        // Correct output:
        // my.friends.friend@test.com
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can implement Breadth First Search to come up with the n(th) degree friends of a member. Create a `Queue` to store the friends in each layer and create a `HashSet` to store visited friends. There may be cycles in the graph, i.e. having a friend's friend as friend, therefore we have to keep track of visited friends in set. In each layer, get the friends of the current member and add it to the queue. Don't forget to check if it is visited before.

In each layer, increment the variable `deg`. If deg is equal to `degree`, then return the elements in the `Queue`. You can find the implementation of it below.

```
public static List<Member> getFriendsOfDegree(Member member, int degree) {
   int deg = 0;
   Queue<Member> q = new LinkedList<>();
   HashSet<Member> visited = new HashSet<Member>();

   q.add(member);
   visited.add(member);

   while(!q.isEmpty()) {
         if(deg == degree) {
             List<Member> friends = new ArrayList<Member>();
             while(!q.isEmpty()) friends.add(q.poll());
             return friends;
         }
         deg++;
         int size = q.size();
         for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
             Member mem = q.poll();
             for(Member friend: mem.getFriends()) {
                 if(!visited.contains(friend)) {
                     q.add(friend);
                     visited.add(friend);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return new LinkedList<Member>();  // cover the edge cases
 }
```

In order to cover the edge cases [here](https://www.testdome.com/questions/java/friends/331), return `new LinkedList<Member>()` at the very end of your function. It simply returns an empty `LinkedList` if there are no n(th) degree friends of the given member.

Output when I run on the website.

> Simple cases: Correct answer  
> Complex cases: Correct answer  
> Edge cases: Correct answer  
> Performance test: Correct answer

If you are not familiar with graph algorithms or in particular with BFS, you can have a look at [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/tutorial/) tutorial.